# Show ModelState errors to te View

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, modelstate

I'm trying to display some errors to the user.

For that i'm working with the `ModelState.isValid` and with the `@Html.ValidationSummary` to display it.

But somehow, it does not work at the moment.

**Model:**

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Account name is required")]
[EmailAddress]
public string CTC_accountName { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
public string CTC_accountPassword { get; set; }
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Submit(RegisterViewModel model)
{
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
          return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "Register", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formAll", style = "margin-top:3%", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{

    <div class="shadow-sm p-2 mb-3 rounded">
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <h5>Personal Details</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="formMember">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CTC_accountName, "Account/Email*")
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CTC_accountName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Email", @id = "CTC_accountName", @autocomplete = "username" } })
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CTC_accountName)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CTC_accountPassword, "Password*")
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CTC_accountPassword, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Password", @id = "CTC_accountPassword", @type = "password", @autocomplete = "current-password" } })
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CTC_accountName)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I appreciate your help

Comment: Is your view named "Submit.cshtml"?

Comment: @howcheng Nope, my view is named Register.cshtml

Comment: That's likely your problem then. If you return `View(model)` then ASP.NET will be looking for a view with the same name of the action. You need `return View("Register", model)` instead.

Comment: Thx for that. Sadly it's still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found what was wrong.

I had a POST call ajax in the submit function I had to remove to see the @Html.ValidationSummary!